# ag-grid inside bootstrap tabs in JSF-App

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, el, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to display some data on a JSF Web-App.

The data is generated via a managed bean which produces a JSON string.

I use EL inside JS to set the rowdata on any HTML Request directly:

```
<ui:composition ...>
<script type="text/javascript">
columnDefinitions = [...]
var rowData = #{fooView.getBarListAsJson()};
var gridOptions = [...]
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
            new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
        });
</script>
<div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-fresh"></div>
```

That xhtml-file can be inserted via `ui:include src="/WEB-INF/components/fooTable.xhtml">` into any other page, which works fine.

As soon as I insert it as a child of `<div id="tab-n" class="tab-pane fade">` using bootstrap's tabs, it doesn't work anymore. The data isn't displayed. Inspecting the sources in the browser shows that the data is generated and assigned to rowData. Still, inside a tab, it's not showing up in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/components/fooTable.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="type" value="1" />
            </ui:include>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/components/fooTable.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="type" value="2" />
            </ui:include>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/components/fooTable.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="type" value="2" />
            </ui:include>
        </div>
</div>
```

creates multiple tables. As the javascript in fooTable.xhtml defined some global variables, sideeffects appeared in the subsequent calls.

Putting everything into `jQuery(document).ready(...)` solved the issue.